# http post in angular error- 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, http, http-post, http-status-code-404

```
var dataObject = { 
    appId: $scope.appId 
}; 
$http({ 
    url: "/mockData/searchResults.json", 
    method: "POST", 
    params: dataObject, 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},     
}).success(function(data, status){ 
    $scope.results = data; 
}).error(function(data, status){ })
```

The below is the error in network

> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
>   Request URL:http://localhost:9000/mockData/searchResults.json?appId=546
>   Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:404 Not Found
>   **Response Headers**
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:51
>   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Date:Fri, 07 Oct 2016 13:58:15 GMT
>   X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
>   **Request Headers**
>   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:0
>   Host:localhost:9000
>   Origin:http://localhost:9000
>   Referer:http://localhost:9000/
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
>   **Query String Parameters**
>   appId:546

Comment: are you sure the server is running, and that you have a post route?

Comment: yes, my grunt server is up and running

Comment: The error message says it all; it can't find that URL. You've posted no code that show there is anything listening at that URL. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].